# Do AI-controlled ships automatically man systems?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

For AI ships, and for the AI-controlled Rebel Flagship, do systems (particularly piloting) count as manned, or do they just rely on autopilot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They must count as manned, or use a different set of dodging equations entirely. The Auto-Scout and Auto-Assault ships have only one level of the Piloting subsystem but are able to dodge.

Comment: I think they're counted as being fully manned as well, and also staffed to repair

Comment: They can also jump.

Comment: They seem to repair much more slowly. I wonder if interrupting actions (e.g. having an invader, fire, etc) cancel the manning. Not sure how I'd find out :D

Comment: @Samthere - Fires have to be put out before repairing your own systems, so I assume its the same for A.I. As for invaders, a repair bot will continue repairing despite taking damage from an enemy boarder, which leads me to believe that the A.I. will continue repairing whilst taking damage. Note however, that the damage you do each hit from a boarder probably cancels out any repair that an A.I. does anyway, because you can still manage to take out A.I. systems with boarders.

Comment: @Samthere - Also, whilst the A.I. repairs more slowly, it has the benefit of repairing everything at once. As such, when fighting the final ship, it is best to keep one crew member alive on board the enemy ship, so he is forced to frantically run around repairing things, as opposed to letting the A.I. take over and repair everything at once.